# Is malloc/free a syscall or a library routine provided by libc?

Tags: c, linux, system-calls, libc

If malloc/free is implemented as a library routine in libc, then is it implemented on top of the *sbrk* syscall or the *mmap* syscall, or something else?

And to be general, does the function declared in *sys/syscall.h* contains ALL the system calls in the target machine?

Comment: If only you had the source to libc...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`malloc` and `free` are standard C library functions which are to be implemented by each C implementation.

The C standard only defines the way in which these functions behave and the behavior expected from them.  How they are to be implemented in left to each implementation.

In short they are implementation detail of the implementation you use.

(An "implementation" consists of the compiler, the linker, the runtime library, and probably a few other things.)

Comment: implemented by the platform's c library, not compiler.

Comment: @kaizer.se: Compiler are free (heh!) to have their own standard library if they want, but there generally isn't much point.

Comment: @kaizer.se: It depends,A compiler can use the standard library implementation provided by the platform or they can provide their own implementation of the same.Which one to choose depends on the compiler.That is the meaning of *Implementation Detail*

Comment: Most commonly, `malloc` and `free` are implemented as library functions that invoke lower-level code.  If an OS happens to provide system calls that exactly match the behavior that the C standard requires for `malloc` and `free, then they could be implemented as system calls.  But I don't know of any OS that does this (even Unix, the birthplace of C).

Answer (score 48):

Very often, `malloc` and `free` are using lower-level virtual memory allocation services and allocating several pages (or even megabytes) at once, using [system calls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) like [mmap](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap) and [munmap](http://linux.die.net/man/2/munmap) (and perhaps [sbrk](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sbrk)). Often `malloc` prefers to reuse *previously* `free`d memory space when relevant. Most `malloc` implementations use various and different strategies for "large" and "small" allocations, etc...

Notice that [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) can be limited, e.g. with [setrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html). Use on Linux [pmap(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pmap.1.html) and [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) to learn more about the virtual address space of some process (e.g. `/proc/self/maps` for your own one or `/proc/1234/maps` - also the `pmap 1234` command - for process of pid 1234).

You could look at your GNU [libc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) source code, look into the source code of other C standard libraries (such as [musl-libc](http://musl-libc.org/)), read about [`malloc` implementations](http://www.malloc.de/papers/malloc-slides.html), choose some [other ones](https://github.com/emeryberger/Malloc-Implementations) or implement your own, or use [strace](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace) to find out experimentally.

Read the [syscalls man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/syscalls) (i.e. [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)) and the file `<asm/unistd.h>` for a list of system calls.

---

#### a very fast `malloc`

<sup>(I believe that this could be the fastest implementation of `malloc`; however it is not very useful; it is conforming to the standards, e.g. [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) or better)</sup>

I strongly believe that the C standard is very vague about `malloc` and `free`. I'm pretty sure that the following functions are respecting the letter (but not the spirit) of the standard:

```
 /* politically incorrect, but very probably standard conforming */
 void *malloc (size_t sz) { if (sz>0) errno = ENOMEM; return NULL; }
 void free(void*ptr) { }
```

Of course you'll code `calloc` and `realloc` accordingly.

<sup>(BTW every code using `malloc` should test against its failure, but some -incorrectly- don't; `malloc` can return `NULL` on failure and people should test against that case)</sup>

---

The GNU libc gives you [hooks](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Hooks-for-Malloc.html) for your own `malloc` functions (and you could even probably use [Boehm's Garbage Collector](http://www.hboehm.info/gc/) transparently thru them). These hooks could become deprecated and are non-standard.

If using GNU libc, look also into [mallinfo(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mallinfo.3.html) and [malloc_stat(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc_stats.3.html) and related functions.

Comment: Actually, `malloc` and `free` can be even simpler, something like `#define malloc(x) NULL` and `#define free(x) (void)1` :-) ISO doesn't require `errno` to be set, that's a POSIX thing. You'd probably also want to intercept `calloc` and `realloc` as well.

Comment: @paxdiablo:are you sure that  `malloc` can be just a macro? I thought it should be a function (assignable to a function pointer)

Comment: Good point, I think you're right, I didn't think of that. You can still ditch the errno settings.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use an alternate implementation for `malloc` and `free` if you use a different memory allocator. For example, the [hoard memory allocator](http://www.hoard.org/) is sometimes used to improve performance of multithreaded applications.