# Memory allocation with malloc in C

Tags: c, memory, pointers, malloc

Here is my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main(){
   char *p1, *p2, *p3, *p4;

   p1 = (char*)malloc(10);
   p2 = (char*)malloc(10);
   p3 = (char*)malloc(16);
   p4 = (char*)malloc(32);

   printf("p1 points at: %d\n", p1);
   printf("p2 points at: %d\n", p2);
   printf("p3 points at: %d\n", p3);
   printf("p4 points at: %d\n\n", p4);

   system("PAUSE");
}
```

This produces the following output on my PC:

**p1 points at: 6492080**

**p2 points at: 6492104**

**p3 points at: 6492128**

**p4 points at: 6492152**

So, each memory space that malloc allocates starts 24 bytes further, no matter how many bytes are allocated. Why is that? I appreciate your help!

Comment: The compiler should have warned you about, your %d format strings.  Pointers are printed using %p. Do you have warnings enabled? Also, don't cast the return from malloc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`malloc` shall allocate space for an object of `size` size. Nothing prevents your implementation to add padding bytes for alignment purpose, for instance. Another example: some memory management implementations keep the size of your block before the allocated space.

If you want more details, you should precise your implementation.

Answer (score 5):

The exact behavior of `malloc` is determined by your particular implentation (compiler/libc/OS).  By printing out the addresses, your program is engaged in undefined behavior.

If you narrowed the scope of your question by telling us what compiler you are using, what OS you are on, what architecture, and what version of libc you are using, then we might be able to give a more specific answer about that implementation and why the number is 24.

My **GUESS** would be that in your implementation, each `malloc`ed region of memory needs to start at an address that is a multiple of 8, and also there are 8 bytes of overhead.

**EDIT:** If you called `malloc` again to create p5 after p4, the pattern definitely cannot continue, so your statement of "each memory space that malloc allocates starts 24 bytes further, no matter how many bytes are allocated." is false.

Comment: Okay, I'm using Dev-C++ compiler v.4.9.9.2 on a Windows 7 64 bit operating system. Where can I find the libc version? Finally, I understand my mistake on the question, but you get the point!

Answer (score 3):

There is no guarantee that an `int` and some `void*` or `char*` pointer have the same size (on my Debian/Linux/AMD64 system, `int`-s are 32 bits but pointers are 64 bits). You might want to include `<stdint.h>` and use `intptr_t`.

The implementation of `malloc` may sometimes reserve a few bytes before the allocated zone for housekeeping purposes. And `malloc` shoud always return an enough aligned pointer ([alignment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment) constraints are compiler, runtime, and processor specific). There is absolutely no guarantee that `malloc` returns an increasing sequence of results in time (especially in real programs, where millions of calls to `malloc` are mixed with millions of calls to `free`; you may even have some [memory fragmentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_fragmentation) in such long running processes).

And I am quite sure that if you add a `p5 = malloc(10120);` after your `p4` you won't see a 24 bytes distance between `p5` and `p4`, since when it is successful `malloc` guarantee that its result is not an [alias](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_alias) of any previous result, so that `p5` should have at least a distance of 32 bytes with `p4` (which contains a 32 bytes chunk).

Almost always, the standard C library implements `malloc` above some lower-level primitive, usually some [syscall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) to fetch consecutive [virtual memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) pages. On Linux, these syscalls are often [mmap(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/mmap.2.html) (perhaps with `sbrk(2)`) and since Linux systems are mostly [free software](http://www.fsf.org/) you could actually study and improve the implementation of `malloc` e.g.  [Musl Libc implementation of malloc](http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/malloc) (the more common GNU libc `malloc` implementation is perhaps more complex to understand). So you could learn more by switching to Linux.

An implementation of `malloc` could in theory [always fail](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8460584/841108). In practice, `malloc` may succeed, but you should always test for the failure case.

Of course, most implementations care about `free` and re-use recently `free`-d memory zone (without any syscalls), if possible, in their `malloc` implementation. How to organize the heap to be able make `malloc` and `free` efficient is difficult (and may be still a research subject, if you want it to be very good).

You might want to read the wikipedia page on [malloc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malloc).