# C - Segmentation Fault when using malloc with large size paramater

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault, malloc

I'm running into a segfault when allocating a dynamic array of large size.

As a specific example, the below code causes a segfault.

```
int max = 1399469912;
int *arr = (int*) malloc((max+1) * sizeof(int));
arr[0] = 1;
```

However, if I replace max with something smaller like 5, then I get no segfault.

Why does this happen? Or, is there another solution to achieve the same effect? I need a dynamically allocated array of significant size.

Thanks

Comment: First of all, [should you really cast the result of `malloc`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)? Secondly, what if the [`malloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) call fails and return a null pointer? You need to *check* for that.

Comment: A is for Ambition.  A is also for Allocation.  Trying to allocate 5.6 gigabytes is a rather *Ambitious Allocation.*

Comment: If the arithmetic is done using 64-bit numbers, you're asking for about 5 GiB of memory.  Does you system allow you to allocate that much?  You must check the return value from `malloc()` before using it.  That isn't always enough (Linux and OOM — Out of Memory — Killer), but it is necessary.

Comment: I have a hunch the OP is trying to do this on a 32 bit OS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reed [documentation of `malloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) (or [malloc(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html) from Linux man page)

It can fail, and then returns `NULL`; and your code should handle that case:

```
int *arr = malloc((max+1) * sizeof(int));
if (!arr) { perror("malloc arr"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
```

You could handle the failure in some other ways, but [errno](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/error/errno) is giving the reason. In practice, recovering a `malloc` or `calloc` failure is quite tricky. In most cases, exiting abruptly like above is the simplest thing to do. In some cases (think of a server program which should run continuously) you can do otherwise (but that is *difficult*).

Read also about [memory overcommitment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_overcommitment) (a whole system configurable thing or feature, that I personally dislike and disable, because it might make `malloc` apparently succeed when memory resources are exhausted; on Linux read about [Out-of-memory killer](https://lwn.net/Articles/317814/))

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8460584/841108) (a silly implementation of `malloc`)

BTW, you need to be sure that `(max+1) * sizeof(int)` is not overflowing, and you'll better define `size_t max = 1399469912;` (not `int`).

Notice that you are requesting (on systems having `sizeof(int)==4` like my Linux/x86-64 desktop) more than five gigabytes. This is a significant amount of [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space).

Comment: How can I determine the cause of failure?

Comment: +1 for the size_tr suggestion even though in case where the size is known at compile time every good compiler will warn you in case of any overflow =)

Answer (score 3):

You have to check whether `malloc` return a valid pointer or fails to allocate the memory. In that case, it returns a `null`. pointer.

```
int max = 1399469912;
int *arr = (int*) malloc((max+1) * sizeof(int));
if( arr == NULL )
{
     /* Malloc failed, deal with it */
}else{
 //fine here
 arr[0] = 1;
}
```

Quoting the `man page`

> If successful, calloc(), malloc(), realloc(), reallocf(), and valloc()
>   functions return a pointer to allocated memory. If there is an error,
>   they return a NULL pointer and set errno to ENOMEM.

Answer (score 2):

`malloc()` returns `NULL` if it wasn't able to allocate the requested memory. You should check the value returned by `malloc()` against `NULL`.