# Access command line arguments in C++

Tags: c++

Is it possible to get the command line arguments without receiving them via int main(int, char**)? I don't want to pass the arguments to multiple methods, so a global function would be perfect. Also, I do not want to store the arguments by myself via global variables. I'm running Windows and Linux.

**edit:**
Example:

```
int main()
{
   int argc = GetArgumentCount();
   char ** argv = GetArguments();
   return 0;
}
```

**edit:**
It's possible to use *LPTSTR WINAPI GetCommandLine(void);* in win32.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683156(v=vs.85).aspx

I'm looking for equivalent functions in Linux.

Comment: It's not necessary to use global variables when reading command line, it's a matter of architecture of the program.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? What's wrong with getting them via `int main(int, char**)`? Can you give us any good reason for not retrieving them from the arguments passed to `main`?

Comment: Very unclear question, because it is lacking motivation.

Comment: Why would a global function be perfect but variables are not?  As others have said, this design seems bad.

Comment: @grimgrom: please **edit your question** to improve it and *add motivation and context*. In general, what you are asking for is crazy.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch A lack of motivation does not make a question unclear. It is very clear what the OP wants. Motivation != Clarity.

Answer (score 7):

> Is it possible to get the command line arguments without receiving
>   them via `int main(int, char**)`?

Yes, with platform-specific functions. But that's not necessary (see below).

> I don't want to pass the arguments to multiple methods,

That's understandable. It's an anti-pattern also known as "tramp data".

> Also, I do not want to store the arguments by myself via global variables.

Yes, global variables are rarely a good idea.

Here's an alternative approach: store them as a `static` local container object in some globally available non-member function which returns the container by reference.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::string>& Arguments()
{
    static std::vector<std::string> arguments;
    return arguments;
}

void f()
{
    // use arguments anywhere else:
    std::cout << Arguments()[0];
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i)
    {
        Arguments().push_back(argv[i]);
    }

    f();
}
```

Of course, this can be made more sophisticated. For example, you might want to prevent anyone else but `main` from changing the vector by wrapping the vector in a class and declaring `main` as a `friend`, something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Arguments final
{
public:
    static int Count()
    {
        return arguments.size();
    }

    static std::string Get(int index)
    {
        return arguments[index];
    };

private:
    Arguments() = delete;
    friend int main(int argc, char* argv[]);
    static std::vector<std::string> arguments;
};

std::vector<std::string> Arguments::arguments;

void f()
{
    // use Arguments anywhere else:
    std::cout << Arguments::Get(0);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i)
    {
        Arguments::arguments.push_back(argv[i]);
    }

    f();
}
```

Note that special care is needed to avoid bugs at program shutdown, when static objects are destroyed. You must make sure that no destructor of a static object accesses `Arguments`, or else you risk undefined behaviour.

Comment: It's a shame that it doesn't seem immediately apparent that C++ has a proper way for handling this in 2017. I mean it seems like each example is primitive and reinvents that primitive wheel; Especially coming from python where getarg is so simple and nice.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to get the command line arguments without receiving them via int main(int, char**) ?

No (at least, *not in portable manner*), however you could put the usual `argc`, `argv` into some *global* variable (or other global data, often after parsing). And that could also be into some `static` data with other functions in  the *same* [translation unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)) retrieving it. Hence a reasonable (readable and portable) approach would be:

```
static int myargc;
static char **myargv;
int GetArgumentCount(void) {
  return myargc;
}
char**GetArguments(void) {
  return myargv;
}
int main(int argc, char**argv) {
   myargc= argc;
   myargv= argv;
   /// etc....
```

Notice that on some systems or some implementations you might access to the command line arguments in some other ways.

#### dirty *Linux specific* tricks

For example, on Linux, using [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html), you might parse `/proc/self/cmdline` but it is unreasonable to do that (on your Linux system, try to run `od -cx /proc/self/cmdline` in your terminal to guess what I mean), so I still recommend using `int main(int argc, char**argv)` and storing, in some global or static data, the `argc` and `argv`, or more probably, do some [parsing of program arguments](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Parsing-Program-Arguments.html).

So on Linux, you might code your `GetArgumentCount` and `GetArguments` functions (by parsing `/proc/self/cmdline`, see also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12237783/841108)) but **it would be foolish to do so** without using `argc` and `argv` from `main` (even if it is technically doable). Coding such a crazy `GetArgumentCount` and `GetArguments` which parses `/proc/self/cmdline` is left as an exercise to the masochistic reader.

<sup>Perhaps you need that because some static data's constructor -running *before* `main` and called before it from [crt0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crt0)- uses them; but in that case, your program's design is IMHO *very wrong*. I have no idea if similar dirty tricks are doable in Windows.</sup>

Comment: "Also, I do not want to store the arguments by myself via global variables."

Comment: Technically, claiming that it's outright impossible is wrong.  It might be more _portable_ to collect argc/argv, but if `ps` (or the task manager or some os equivalent) can show you your command line arguments, surely you can get them the same way `ps` (or task manager or os equivalent) does.

Comment: @HWalters; thanks for your comment, which inspired me a better answer.  But my answer above is as wicked as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47122805/841108) one (which got downvoted).

Comment: On Windows, you can use [`GetCommandLineW()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683156.aspx) and [`CommandLineToArgvW()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776391.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If you really think that is a good idea, you can easily make cor command line arguments global:

```
int argc_ = 0;
char** argv_ = NULL;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    argc_ = argc;
    argv_ = argv;

    // ...
}
```