# Is this a correct use of realloc()?

Tags: c, malloc, stdin, realloc

I want to be able to have a user enter what they wish to do. There will be other options but for now I am working on "insert". The other two options will be "search" and "delete".

```
int main() {

    char *input = malloc(sizeof(char) * 6);
    printf("%s", "WELCOME TO USER'S SKIP LIST!\n\nWhat do you wish to do? ");
    scanf("%6s", input);
    if (strcmp(input, "insert") == 0) {
        printf("%s", "What is the item? ");
        input = realloc(input, (size_t)scanf("%s", input));
    }
}
```

I initially allocate enough memory for `input` to have 6 characters. This is because the other two options will also only have 6 characters. After they enter `insert` they will have to enter an item that will have any number of characters, so I want to reallocate memory for `input` based on what they enter for an item. So if they enter `Nintendo Switch` there will be a reallocation for 15 characters. Is my implementation of `realloc()` the correct way of doing this?

Comment: You are not *implementing* `realloc`, you are using it (wrongly).

Comment: :"Is my implementation of realloc() the correct way of doing this?" --> No. `scanf("%6s", input);` allows to read too big an input.   `realloc()` uses wrong size and fails to check for out-of--memory.  At least 5 issues with this code.

Comment: OT: regarding: `char *input = malloc(sizeof(char) * 6);`  1) the expression: `sizeof( char )` is defined in the C standard as 1.  Multipling anything by 1 has absolutely no effect.  Suggest removing that expression, it is just cluttering the code.  2)  when calling any of the heap allocation functions: `malloc` `calloc` `realloc`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful. 3) when calling `realloc()`, save the result into a temp variable, check it, and if good, then copy to the target variable.  This avoids a memory leak if `realloc()` fails.

Comment: regarding: `scanf("%6s", input);`  1) when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful. 2) the string: `insert` takes 7 characters due to the trailing NUL byte.  SO the call to `malloc` should be allocating 7 characters, not 6

Comment: regarding: `scanf("%s", input)` what are you expecting this to do?  `scanf()` returns the number of successful input/conversions, not the length of the input

Answer (score 5):

I suppose you're primarily asking about this:

> ```
>     input = realloc(input, (size_t)scanf("%s", input));
> ```

No, it is not a correct ***use*** of `realloc()`.  There are at least four distinct problems with that line alone, including:

- `scanf()` returns the number of input items successfully scanned and recorded, or `EOF` if an error occurs.  "Input items" correspond to field directives, such as your `%s`, so that particular `scanf()` call will never return a value greater than 1.  It might, however, return either 0 or `EOF` (usually -1).
- Even if `scanf()` did return the number of characters read,

  - Any reallocation would be too late.  The data are stored into the provided space by `scanf()`, and if the space is not large enough then its bounds will be overrun prior to any opportunity for reallocation.
  - No space is reserved for a string terminator.
  - `realloc()` can fail, in which case it returns `NULL`.  Even if you check for that by examining `input` after the `realloc()`, you will no longer have a pointer to the original space, so it leaks.

Answer (score 4):

**Read *carefully* the documentation of [`scanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf), of [`malloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc), of [`realloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc)**, so read them several times. You could also refer to the C11 standard [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) which mentions them (in [§7.22.3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.3)).

> Is this a correct implementation of realloc()?

**You are not *implementing* `realloc`**. Here is a joke-implementation of it (see also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8460584/841108) joke-implementation of `malloc`):

```
void *realloc(void*ptr, size_t siz) {
  errno = ENOMEM;
  return NULL;
}
```

Of course you would actually use a *serious* implementation of `realloc` (not the joke above), and it is provided by your [C standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library) implementation (e.g. above [operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) primitives or [system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) like [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) on Linux).

So, no, you don't have any *implementation* of  `realloc` (and you would *use* the `realloc`  already implemented in your C standard library). And (on Linux at least) you can study the implementation of `realloc` because it usually is implemented inside some [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) (e.g. [musl-libc](https://musl-libc.org/) or GNU [glibc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/)). [Here](https://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/malloc/malloc.c#n369) (in its file `src/malloc/malloc.c` line 369) is `musl-libc` implementation of `realloc`.

### you are wrongly *using* `realloc`

Then, you are using  [`scanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) as `scanf("%s", input)`. But `scanf` returns `EOF` on failure, and the number of successfully input values on success. Usually `EOF` is -1. So in your case, that `scanf("%s", input)` can return -1 (on failure), 0 (if no input value has been processed) or 1 (if it has put something in `input`).

The [`size_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/size_t) type is some *unsigned* integral type. On my Linux/x86-64 system, it is an unsigned 64 bits number, same as `unsigned long`. So `(size_t)(-1)` becomes a *huge* number, i.e. 2<sup>64</sup> - 1. Then `realloc` will surely fail (because my system don't have that much memory) if given that `(size_t)(-1)` so `realloc(input, (size_t)-1)` should give `NULL`.

If `realloc` is given `(size_t)0`, it is documented on Linux (see [realloc(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/realloc.3.html)) to do what `free` does: release the given memory. But the C standard don't require that behavior.

If `realloc` is given `(size_t)1`, if would (or at least is permitted to) *shrink* the memory zone (to only hold one byte, which is not enough for your needs).

### So your program is *completely* wrong

BTW, you need to handle failure of `realloc`, so coding `input = realloc(input, newsize);` is very naive.

Also, your `scanf("%6s", input);` is wrong (potential [buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow), for an input of exactly six bytes) since you need the space for the terminating <kbd>NUL</kbd> character.

So, **throw your program to the garbage bin.** Take some rest (or some fun). Read the documentation of standard functions (and the wikipage of [C dynamic memory allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation)). Think a little bit. And **rewrite your program entirely.**

Then compile your program with all warnings and debug info: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/). Improve your code to get no warnings. Ensure that your program handle the failure cases (of `scanf`, of  `malloc`, of `realloc`, etc...). Read [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Use the [`gdb` debugger](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/) and [valgrind](https://valgrind.org/). Be [scared](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46526702/841108) of [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

For your program (the one you rewrite from scratch), you could be interested in using [fgets](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) (or even, on Linux, [getline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) or [readline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readline.3.html)...) for input. You may sometimes want to clear the input buffer with [memset](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memset) before doing the actual input.

Be aware that [stdio](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io) is buffered, and `stdout` is usually line-buffered. So take the habit of ending your [`printf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) format string with `\n` or use [`fflush`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fflush) appropriately.

PS. `valgrind` is [available](http://valgrind.org/info/platforms.html) on Linux (but not on Windows), and that is one of the many reasons making Linux a very developer- and student- friendly operating system. So I do recommend using some [Linux distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_distribution) to learn C programming.