# Does the heap in C++ contain classes and structure objects or does it just contain pointers?

Tags: c++, heap-memory

I was reading that Objects in Java are in the heap, but I was wondering if that is also the case for C++ or any programming language.

Comment: C++ doesn't have a concept of the heap.  What it has is objects with automatic storage duration and objects with dynamic storage duration.  How that is implemented is up to the implementation.

Comment: @NathanOliver: The fact that the C++ standard does not define the heap does not negate the fact that heaps exist and are widely used to implement C++, and asking what is in them is a valid question.

Comment: When a heap exists and is used for dynamic storage duration objects in `c++` (implementation detail) it would contain objects if you dynamically allocated the objects.

Answer (score 3):

*Heap* is not a word used by the C++ language in this context. Heap is an area of virtual memory provided by the operating system (from a very abstract, high level point of view). Memory allocated from the *free store* in C++ is typically allocated from the heap by the language implementation. That is an implementation detail.

> Does the heap in C++ contain classes ...

No. *Classes* do not have storage in C++. They are not contained in memory.

*Objects* have storage. A dynamically allocated object is stored in the free store, which is typically in the heap memory.

> ... and structure objects or does it just contain pointers?

Pointers, just like instances of classes (including structures), are also objects. Just like objects of other types, pointers too can be allocated in dynamic, automatic or static (and other) storage.

---

> I was reading that Objects in Java are in the heap, but I was wondering if that is also the case for C++ ...

No. Only dynamically allocated objects "are in the heap" (note though the caveat that this is an implementation detail). Objects in automatic storage are "on the stack" (another area of virtual memory, another implementation detail). Objects with static storage are in yet another area of memory.

Given that the location is an implementation detail, it is possible for an object to only exist in a register of the processor, and not in memory at all.

> ... or any programming language.

It is not universally true for all programming languages. After all, I've told you that it is not true for C++. There are other languages besides C++ that have a concept of distinct storage durations. Rather obviously, C being another example.

There are however many dynamic languages for which your statement does apply.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ and C the [heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management#HEAP) -it is an [abstraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraction_(computer_science))- contains (conceptually) memory zones. Read wikipage on [C dynamic memory allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation) (most of it also applies to C++). At the [operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) level, the heap is made of several segments in the [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) which has grown at runtime (thru [system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) like [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) on Linux, indirectly called by `malloc` and/or `::operator new`). And in theory the heap could be non-existent or empty (see this [`malloc` joke-implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8460584/841108) and adapt it to C++).

A memory zone (it can be in the heap, it could also be on the [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack)) *may* contain an object. It may also contain some other aggregate (e.g. arrays). And it could also contain garbage (or a mix of all these).

Sometimes, a memory zone is not yet initialized, then (at that moment) it contains garbage. For example, the result of `::operator new`, or of `malloc` can be uninitialized memory.

A related and important notion is [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

What matters is the [storage duration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration) of your objects. [Automatic variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_variable) are *conceptually* on the call stack (which is *not* mentioned in the C++11 standard [n3337](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/blob/master/papers/n3337.pdf)), but some of them simply sit in [processor registers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_register) in practice (per the [as-if rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/As-if_rule)). Read more about [dynamic memory management](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) in C++.

An important difference between Java and C++ is their [memory management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management). The Java language mandates a [garbage collector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)). But C++ is based on [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization) so favors [reference counting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting) (which could be considered as some poor GC technique which does not handle correctly [circular references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_reference)) and [smart pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer).

**C++ is a *very* difficult programming language** (I don't claim to master it, even if I can code in C++). You'll need years to learn C++. Start by reading some good [C++ programming](http://stroustrup.com/Programming/) book. See also some [C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) site.

I believe that the terminology and concepts of garbage collection are useful even to C++ programmers (because in *some* cases, you'll end up implementing a specialized GC in your application; be aware of [Greenspun's tenth rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenspun%27s_tenth_rule)). So read the [GC handbook](https://gchandbook.org/).

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Not my downvote, and the following does not apply to your answer: in general, there's plenty of junk in the C++ tag already, and bad questions should not be encouraged with answers. Now, this is not a great question, but there's just so much utter flotsam that's far worse. Hence, I don't think it's worthy of a downvote. Plenty of other junk to downvote. But it's probably a dupe, so I might spend a few seconds searching for one, instead.

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr in C++, variables are stored directly in something akin to Java's 'stack', but they might as an implementation detail be backed up by data allocated on something akin to Java's 'heap'.

My answer only applies to common C++ implementations, and not to the language itself (e.g. I'm sure embedded systems are quite different).  I'm also ignoring [dynamic storage duration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration) (what you get with the `new` and `delete` keywords in C++) because that isn't very useful most of the time.

In Java, you have the idea of the stack.  It holds primitives, and it holds references to instantiations of classes (I'm not going to use the word "object" here because [it means something very different in C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object)).  The actual class instantiation sits somewhere else: on the heap.  `==` in Java compares only the stack value and ignores the heap value.

Meanwhile, in C++, when you define a class, e.g.

```
class Foo {
  double data;
  std::string more_data;
};
```

And then instantiate it

```
Foo foo = {5.0, "enough data to to prevent the short string optimization from happening"};
```

Then that puts both of `Foo`'s data members directly on the 'stack'.  The expression `sizeof(Foo)` will tell you how much 'stack' memory is needed by any instantiation of `Foo` (note that it is always the same, and is a feature of the type `Foo` and doesn't vary at runtime).

Of course, `Foo`'s `std::string` data member can handle arbitrarily-sized strings.  In order to do that, typical `std::string` implementations hold a pointer to a dynamically allocated chunk of memory.  That chunk is likely allocated when a variable of type `Foo` is instantiated with a non-empty string, and then it is deallocated (as per `std::string`'s destructor) when that variable goes out of scope.  That's your 'heap'.  Pretty much anything which needs to store an amount of data which varies at runtime will use the 'heap'.

Comment: Most standard containers -and `std::string` itself- do use dynamic memory (internally), even when the containers themselves are stack-allocated

Answer (score -2):

The so-called heap is memory that a program may use for any purpose. It is used to implement objects, store data, and more.