# Is this a portable strdup

Tags: c

I have a c program I'm writing that I want to be portable and future compliant. The POSIX function `strdup()` is not in the current C standard, but it has been added to the C2x standard. Will this code work properly with C standard compliant compilers in the future.

Will it work on both POSIX and non POSIX systems?

**my_strdup.h**

```
#ifndef MY_STRDUP_H
#define MY_STRDUP_H

#include <string.h>

#ifndef strdup
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#if _MSC_VER > 1920
#define strdup _strdup
#endif
#else
#define strdup mystrdup      
#endif
#endif

char* mystrdup(const char* string_to_copy);
unsigned char* ucstrdup(const unsigned char* string_to_copy);

#endif  // MY_STRDUP_H
```

**my_strdup.c**

```
#include "my_strdup.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* mystrdup(const char* string_to_copy)
{
    char* return_string = NULL;
    size_t length = strlen(string_to_copy);
    ++length;

    return_string = calloc(length, sizeof(*return_string));
    if (return_string)
    {
        memcpy(return_string, string_to_copy, length - 1);
    }

    return return_string;
}

unsigned char* ucstrdup(const unsigned char* string_to_copy)
{
    unsigned char* return_string = NULL;
    size_t length = strlen((const char*)string_to_copy);
    ++length;

    return_string = calloc(length, sizeof(*return_string));
    if (return_string)
    {
        memcpy(return_string, string_to_copy, length - 1);
    }

    return return_string;
}
```

### Post Answer Update:

This code is part of a project I am working on, the code that uses this code can be found in 4 questions on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com). Those questions are all related to unit tests I am writing for [this project](https://github.com/pacmaninbw/VMWithEditor).

Here are the questions on code review in the order asked:

1. [Hand Coded State Driven Lexical Analyzer in C With Unit Test Part A](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/248559/hand-coded-state-driven-lexical-analyzer-in-c-with-unit-test-part-a)
2. [Hand Coded State Driven Lexical Analyzer in C With Unit Test Part B](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/248560/hand-coded-state-driven-lexical-analyzer-in-c-with-unit-test-part-b)
3. [Part C](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/248561/hand-coded-state-driven-lexical-analyzer-in-c-with-unit-test-part-c)
4. [Follow up to Part C](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/248817/common-unit-testing-code-follow-up)

Feel free to write answers for the questions as long as they follow the [Code Review Guidelines](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Looks fine to me. But you don't need to duplicate all that code. Just have `ucstrdup()` call `strdup()` with appropriate casts.

Comment: Will `strdup()` be a macro for certain?  It seems unlikely.

Comment: What is your program doing?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler in the `gcc` string.h file all of the functions are macros.

Comment: @pacmaninbw really ? `extern char *strdup (const char *__s)
     __attribute__ ((__nothrow__ , __leaf__)) __attribute__ ((__malloc__)) __attribute__ ((__nonnull__ (1)));` it does not look like macro for me

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch This code is [part of a code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/248817/common-unit-testing-code-follow-up?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: do you review your own code?  interesting .......

Comment: That’s allowed; it isn’t required. So your test may fail on some systems with `strdup()` provided.  You should probably plan to detect an appropriate version in `__STDC_VERSION__`.  The official number for that won’t be known for a while, but you could make a reasonable guess, such as it will be larger than `202001L`.

Comment: @P__J__ look at the linked code reviews, there are 3 others. That's the only one of my own questions I ever reviewed.

Comment: @P__J__ https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libssp/ssp/string.h

Comment: `#if __MISC_VISIBLE || __POSIX_VISIBLE >= 200809 || __XSI_VISIBLE >= 4
char  *_EXFUN(strdup,(const char *));
#endif
char  *_EXFUN(_strdup_r,(struct _reent *, const char *));
#if __POSIX_VISIBLE >= 200809
char  *_EXFUN(strndup,(const char *, size_t));
#endif
char  *_EXFUN(_strndup_r,(struct _reent *, const char *, size_t));`

Comment: @pacmaninbw as you see there is no one string.h

Comment: @pacmaninbw I would not use calloc to zero only 1 char. also ++length when you use it later only once makes not sense. computer will have to calculate ++ and then -1.

Comment: The *Functions* in `string.h` are provide in [gcc -master - string/](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=tree;f=string;h=9e9479f3c362e0d5886287173eaad4324e1fc5b5;hb=refs/heads/master)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read *carefully* the C11 standard [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf). For things like [Arduino](https://arduino.cc/), you might not even have any `malloc`, and you could have some free-standing implemention of C11.

As a concrete example, the [Linux kernel](https://kernel.org/) is coded in C, and your code could not be part of it.

Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8460584/841108) providing some funny implementation of `malloc` (you could extend it to `calloc`...)

> Will this code work properly with C standard compliant compilers in the future.

### Of course not in general.

Look on many examples of toy operating systems on [OSDEV](https://osdev.org/).

You could have some operating system without  `malloc` or `calloc` but with a C compiler.

> I have a c program I'm writing that I want to be portable and future compliant.

The motto I read somewhere is: **there is no such thing as portable programs, just programs which have been ported** (to some given systems)

Did you consider some approach inspired by [GNU autoconf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoconf) ? Your [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) could use preprocessing tricks and/or generate C code with e.g. [GPP](https://logological.org/gpp.html), [SWIG](https://swig.org/) or other tools.

Comment: He's obviously not targeting freestanding implementations, just non-POSIX.

Comment: If you don’t have `free()`, it doesn’t make sense to worry about whether `strdup()` works.

Comment: Where does the C standard which you linked say that allocation functions are optional?

Comment: A freestanding implementation does not have to provide any `malloc`

Comment: I've downloaded the C11 standard you pointed to and will read through it tomorrow. I doubt I would use the code in the header file on in the Linux Kernel and I would be very careful with any memory allocation in a kernel.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I abandoned the approach I was taking and unconditionally provide a strdup() replacement called [SSF_strdup()](https://github.com/pacmaninbw/VMWithEditor/blob/master/VMWithEditor/safe_string_functions.c).