# calloc problem - malloc.c:2385 error - how does calloc/malloc work?

Tags: c, malloc, calloc

When running my program I receive following error:

> malloc.c:2385: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == initial_top (av) &&
> old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= MINSIZE && prev_inuse
> (old_top) && ((unsigned long) old_end & (pagesize - 1)) == 0)' failed.

The complete code is huge, but I have managed to find something interesting in reproduction, and I cannot understand why this is happening. Any help and/or explanation would be very much appreciated.

Here is a snippet of the code when it is not failing:

```
static void adjacent_list_get(struct elem **elem_list,
                          struct elem *element,
                          uint32_t *size) {

struct elem **t_elem_list;

t_elem_list = calloc((size_t) 1, sizeof(*t_elem_list));     

if (!elem_list) {       
...
```

And here is a snippet of the code when it fails:

```
static void adjacent_list_get(struct elem **elem_list,
                          struct elem *element,
                          uint32_t *size) {

struct elem **t_elem_list;

if (!elem_list) {   
        t_elem_list = calloc((size_t) 1, sizeof(*t_elem_list)); 
        ...
```

During execution, `elem_list` is `NULL`, so the `if` statement is true and it enters that block; but then it fails with error mentioned above.

I cannot understand how the same line, same `calloc` can fail in the same function depending on if it is inside or out of the `if` block. I am missing something here, and I could not find any explanation on the internet.

Comment: You are probably corrupting some heap memory that is used by the memory manager for bookkeeping, most likely due to a buffer overflow. Just by looking at the snippets of code you presented this is hard to track. I'd recommend rebuilding your program with ASAN, which will probably detect the corruption when it happens.

Comment: Run your code through valgrind.  If you're mismanaging memory it will tell you where.

Comment: Ok, so if I understood correctly, this is just a symptom of a problem that is somewhere else?

Comment: Not necessarily, but most likely.

Comment: Ok so this is a typical undefined behavior bug. You have fishy code somewhere, maybe causing a heap corruption. Can't reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

> how does calloc/malloc work?

## It depends a lot of your implementation.

Some implementations of `calloc/malloc` are open source: try installing [Debian](https://debian.org/) on your laptop, study the source code of [GNU libc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) or [musl-libc](https://musl-libc.org/), and read [Linux From Scratch](https://linuxfromscratch.org/). Then `malloc` would *sometimes* use system calls like [mmap(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) or [sbrk(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sbrk.2.html). Most of the time `malloc` would reuse previously `free`d memory zones.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8460584/841108) for a joke-implementation of `malloc` which I believe is conforming to some C standard (e.g. [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) or better).

On the other hand, reading the source code of `malloc` inside Windows is reserved to a very few happy fews.

On microcontrollers like [Arduino](https://arduino.cc/), `malloc` works very differently.

Comment: Maybe that literally answers the question in the title, but that is not actually OP’s problem. Likely they are corrupting memory.

Comment: _reading the source code of malloc inside Windows is reserved to a very few happy fews._ nah ... https://www.ma-no.org/en/software/operating-systems/a-dev-compile-and-install-windows-xp-and-server-2003-from-filtered-source-code

Comment: @DavidRanieri Reading the whole source code of Windows in search of the heap routines doesn't sound like something that would place me in a category called "happy fews". I did something similar reading the Linux kernel and went from Linux fan to someone maintaining a 10 meter safety distance to all Linux computers. Didn't make me happy at all.

Comment: @Lundin  `find` and `grep` are your friends, yes, put the source code in a linux device, or install and use those utilities on windows if you prefer (I don't remember the name of the package but it works fine)

Comment: @DavidRanieri I was just saying that reading this kind of highly specialized huge code base, that's been through some 30 years of maintenance with the mandatory "code rot", isn't exactly what I do to reach a happy place :)

Comment: @Lundin I agree, musl is a poem compared with GNU libc and MS libc (win32 or whatever is the name of the standard library in MS), but is there, you have full access to the implementation :)